# How can I pass a variable to an anonymous inner class in Java?

Tags: java

I have the following method:

```
 public Promise<List<SearchResult>> search(String searchTerms, SearchType type) {
    Promise<List<SearchResult>> response = WS.url(type.url + searchTerms).
            get().map(
            new Function<WSResponse, List<SearchResult>>() {
                public List<SearchResult> apply(WSResponse response) {
                    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(response.getBody());
                    Elements results = doc.select(type.selector);
                    return buildResultList(results);
                }
            }
    );
    return response;
}
```

which doesn't compile because the anonymous inner class doesn't have access to the `SearchType` parameter being passed into the `search` method.

I was wondering how I can get access to this parameter inside the anonymous class?

The way I have written my class is to duplicate this search method for each `SearchType` - i.e. I have three different search methods (with different names) but I wanted to have some code reuse, hence why I am trying to rewrite the method with the `SearchType` parameter being passed in.

Comment: What does the error message say? It might be worthwhile to search for it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mark the `type` parameter as `final`, then you can use it from inside the anonymous inner class.